# Is it necessary to remove "/instance/" keyword that exists in eclipse preferences epf file to set Eclipse plugin_customization.ini?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

In our RCP I changed some preferences then I exported the preferences via Export... button.

In the exported .epf file I found the line that reflects my preferences change.

The line in epf file starts with /instance/org.eclipse.ui.workbench...

My question is : is it necessary to delete this keyword " /instance/ " or can I put it  with " /instance/ " keyword to provide the scope like " /instance/ " or " /configuration/ " ? What happens if I omit these keywords, what appears to be the default ?

Comment: I deleted text " /instance/ " it worked. But there is no info about default value and what happens when I put  /configuration/ . There is a link of vogella abut preferences scope, how to apply them ? ( http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html#preferences-and-scopes )